# Authorization using LDAP OU or Groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, groups, organizational-unit

In the below image I have drawn two schema structures for LDAP(Active Directory) I would like to know which one is correct.

[image]

In my organisation they are using **Structure 1** design for PC login and Cyberoam(network security).
Now I have to install [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.org/) which is a bug tracking software which has a LDAP module while configuring it I don't know what to fill in the field which I shown below

[image]

Because of that I'm doubtful whether our LDAP structure is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure 1 isn't wrong as such if it works for the intended use case, but it limits the flexibility of the LDAP tree and might make some things impossible down the road, e.g. the thing you try to do now. Therefore, I would consider Structure 2 the better solution, as it is much more flexible.

If you want to limit access to your new system e.g. to the IT department, you can work around this by simply give `ou=IT Department` as the container for the user objects (or even as the base DN if your tool doesn't support the configuration of the user container) and ignore the "Allowed groups" parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that the Structure 2 is better. I would like to know is it ***good practice*** to create a group specifically for this bug tracking.

Comment: Controlling things like that is one of the main reason for the existence of groups, so yes, it's a good idea to do it.

Answer (score -2):

Both structures are a representation of the same.
For you it is more important to know what directory service is used.

Y

Comment: I believe they both are not the same because when in "Structure 1" I cannot give OU(Accounts Department) for ALLOWED GROUPS field in bug genie.